# ec2 instance connects to some webservers and not others

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, connection, timeout

I have created a ubuntu server ec2 on AWS and have designated an elastic IP. I've enabled inbound traffic over port 80 and am able to reach this instance from my home computer but not from an external provider (connection timeout).  I have not black listed any IPs and am having difficulty determining why my home server can reach the instance, but when trying to connect to it from the web host there's a connection timeout error.

Firewalls all seem fine on AWS, and I went to another location and was able to connect to AWS from my local computer from there as well (different ip).

Comment: If it is working for you from multiple locations, but not from one specific location, then it is likely to be caused by the non-working location blocking traffic or the configuration of the computer from which you are running the request. Your setup within AWS is likely to be fine.

Comment: You can also turn on VPC flow logs that will log the IP traffic flow.

Comment: It's strange... it works from my home pc, my work pc but not from two separate webservers (California/New York)

Comment: Maybe it is some kind of proxy on your Cal/NY server blocking it

Comment: That's what I thought too, but the sysadmins say they don't block anything...!?